# Too many withColumn statements?

Tags: pyspark

I'm relatively new to Spark. Right now I'm working on a dataset which is really messy. As a result, I had to write a lot of withColumn statements that change strings in a column. I just counted them and in total I have a like 35. Most of them change only two or three columns, over and over again. My statements look as follows:

```
.withColumn(
   "id",
   F.when(
      (F.col("country") == "SE") &
      (F.col("company") == "ABC"),
      "22030"
   ) \
   .otherwise(F.col("id"))
)
```

Anyways, sometimes, I succeed in running the dataset, sometimes I don't. It seems to crash my driver. Is this a problem because there are too many withColumn statements? My understanding is that this shouldn't cause a collect, so they can be executed on the workers independently, right? Also, the dataset itself doesn't have a lot of rows, approximately 25000. Or is there something wrong in the way I tackle the problem? Should I rewrite the withColumn statements? How can I find out where the problem lies?

Comment: How about showing more of the code and the error. They should be running on workers / executors I would hazard a guess.

Comment: Share your other code pieces plz it does not have anything to do with withColumn statement

Comment: Hi guys, I think I found the issue. At the end of the code, I did a forward fill, because one column had missing values and that apparently caused the problem. The way I solved it was that before the forward fill with F.last(...), I ran a select that only returned the columns I really needed. Now it works. I thought since the data set only has like 30000 rows, that won't crush the driver, but apparently it did.